# Getting error while implementing Menu in the blackberry app

Tags: blackberry-jde

I had implemented menu in my app successfully.
But I am facing one another problem,
When I click on the button menu appears as context menu.
I don't want that menu to be appear while I am clicking on button field.

in constructor

```
addMenuItem(_mnu_showresult);
addMenuItem(_mnu_quit);
```

/*declared menu item*/

```
private MenuItem _mnu_showresult = new MenuItem(new StringProvider(
        "Show Result"), 110, 1) {
    public void run() {      
        Dialog.alert("You had scored ");
    }
};
private MenuItem _mnu_quit = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Quit"), 110, 2) {
    public void run() {

    }
};
```

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't paste the initialization code of the *`ButtonField`*. You may need to add the style bit *`ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK`* on that *`ButtonField`* (which triggers the context menu to appear).

Use something like the following to create that button:

```java
ButtonField myButton = new ButtonField("My Button", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
```